# Unsupported media type error on postman after giving content type header and @consume annotation?

Tags: java, tomcat, postman, rest

I am doing a rest api web service in jersey framework, using tomcat and postman, This is my code and I want to accept xml request,

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public JSONObject langurl(language l1){
        String lang=l1.getLang();
        system.out.println(lang);

}
```

JSON request from postman is accepting without any problem but while sending xml request it showing unsupported media error even after setting content type header to application/xml and selected raw and XML in body part.

My POST request in postman body is

```
<language>
   <lang>English</lang>
</language>
```

and my language class is

```
@XmlRootElement
public class language{
   private string lang;
   publuc String getlang(){
      return lang;
   }
   public void setLang(String lang){
      this.lang=lang;
   }
}
```

the same in json format is working, How to resolve this? kindly help me I am new to these concepts.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Postman under the Headers Tab, add a new Line with the KEY **Accept** and the VALUE **application/json**.

This should should work. I  not add another one with
KEY **Content-Type** and VALUE **application/json**

Comment: did the same, added content type as application/xml and Accept as application/json but didn't work @Andreas Radauer